# Jquery get text file and return the value to other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can any one help me what im wrong in

```
function separateerror()
{
    var jqxhr = $.get("/errormsg.txt", function(data) {
        line = data;
        array = line.split(',');
        getmsg=array[0];
    })
    return getmsg;
}
```

i need to return "getmsg" to another function, but its not working, where as if i add alert inbetween

```
function separateerror()
{
    var jqxhr = $.get("/errormsg.txt", function(data) {
        line = data;
        array = line.split(',');
        getmsg=array[0];
    })
    //alert(getmsg)
    return getmsg;
}
```

the value returns, what wrong im doing in code?

Comment: how/where are you calling this function `separateerror`??

Answer (score 3):

`$.get` is an async call and what happens is that if you add an alert in between, you give time for the async call to finish and then your value is already set by the time the `separateerror` function finishes. Otherwise, the `separateerror` function returns before the `$.get` call finishes and then your `getmsg` is probably still a null value.

While working with async calls you should not use this simple model of calling functions and expecting theirs values in return, you should use [callback functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) to accomplish that the right way.

EDIT:
Also, you should handle the `$.get` error callback, in case something happens and you can not load the `txt` file.

```
function separateerror()
 {
    var jqxhr = $.get("/errormsg.txt", function(data) {
       line = data;
       array = line.split(',');
       getmsg=array[0];
       dosomething(getmsg);
    })
    .error(function() { alert("error"); });
}

function dosomething(msg) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert that to the top of your script. That /should/ fix it.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  async: false
});
```

Comment: What if he needs more ajax calls - it would be better if they were asynchronous.

Comment: This will work, but it is not a fix as the asynchronous behavior is the one expected. This is a good hack if you do not need any asynchronous calls whatsoever now and in the future. If you ever need to perform a async calls in the future, get ready for some headaches

Comment: True. Guess that's why you have more rep than I do. I never thought about what would happen after this was invoked. I just thought about a quick fix to a problem. I have much to learn, thanks, guys.